# Strong tournaments

Tags: graph-theory, cycles

Let $T$ be a strong tournament, and let $N=v_1v_2 \cdots v_n$ be an enumeration of $V(T)$. Let $C$ be a circuit in $T$. We define $i_N(C)=|\{(v_i,v_j) \in E(C); i>j\}|$. Suppose that $N$ is chosen in such a way that $i_N(C_1)+ \cdots + i_N(C_t)$ is minimum, where $C_1, \cdots, C_t$ are all the circuits of $T$.

Prove that $\forall i$ such that $1 \le i \le n-1$, $(v_i,v_{i+1}) \in E(T)$ and that $(v_n,v_1) \in E(T)$.

**My attempt:**

I already proved that $\forall i$ such that $1 \le i \le n-1$ we have $(v_i,v_{i+1})\in E(T)$.

I first assumed that $(v_i,v_{i+1}) \not \in E(T)$, and this gives that $(v_{i+1},v_{i})\in E(T)$, so I took the enumeration $N'=v_1 \cdots v_{i-1}v_{i+1}v_iv_{i+2} \cdots v_n$, and proved that $i_{N'}(C_1)+ \cdots + i_{N'}(C_t)< i_N(C_1)+ \cdots + i_N(C_t)$, which is a contradiction.

But for proving $(v_n,v_1) \in E(T)$ I supposed that $(v_1,v_n) \in E(T)$ and tried to take the enumeration $N''=v_nv_1\cdots v_{n-1}$ but I wasn't able to get to a contradiction, since to get to a contradiction from this enumeration I must be sure that the number of forward edges going to $v_n$ was less than that of the backward edges from $v_n$ in the first enumeration, can I prove this?Or do I take 2 cases if the number of forward edges was less or more than that of the  backward edges? Or is there another enumeration that can finish it?

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an excercise from a book? You should give a reference wher you get your question from.

Comment: @András, Actually it is not from a book. Do you have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: You seem to be using $E$ for an enumeration of the vertices, and also for the set of directed edges.

Comment: Yes you're right I'll change that

Comment: Do you allow your circuits to visit the same vertex numerous times? If so, what restrictions do you put on the circuits in order to justify the finite enumeration $C_1,\ldots,C_t$?

Comment: No the circuits pass through a single vertex only 1 time.

Comment: Then I don't understand your concern below (in the comments to the proposed answer) about the possibility that $(v_1,v_2),(v_1,v_3),(v_1,v_4)\in E(C)$. If this were to happen then the circuit $C$ would pass through $v_1$ several times.

Comment: But in any case, the enumeration $N'$ in the answer below does provide a contradiction to the assumption $(v_n,v_1)\not\in E(T)$. Indeed, given a circuit $C$, there are three cases:

Comment: Case 1: $C$ does not involve $v_1$. Then clearly $i_N(C)=i_{N'}(C)$ since the enumeration is the same on all other vertices.

Comment: Case 2: $C$ involves $v_1$, but $(v_1,v_n)\not\in E(C)$. Then there are $1<i,j<n$ such that $(v_i,v_1),(v_1,v_j)\in E(C)$. When computing $i_N(C)$, $(v_i,v_1)$ contributes $+1$ and $(v_1,v_j)$ contributes $+0$. When computing $i_{N'}(C)$, $(v_i,v_1)$ contributes $+0$ and $(v_1,v_j)$ contributes $+1$. The rest of the edges in $C$ contribute the same counts to $i_{N}(C)$ and $i_{N'}(C)$ since they do not involve $v_1$. So $i_N(C)=i_{N'}(C)$.

Comment: Case 3: $(v_1,v_n)\in E(C)$. Then there is $1<i<n$ such that $(v_i,v_1)\in E(C)$. When computing $i_N(C)$, $(v_1,v_n)$ contributes $+0$ and $(v_i,v_1)$ contributes $+1$. When computing $i_{N'}(C)$, $(v_1,v_n)$ and $(v_i,v_1)$ both contribute $+0$. The rest of the edges in $C$ contribute the same counts to $i_{N}(C)$ and $i_{N'}(C)$ since they do not involve $v_1$. So $i_{N'}(C)=i_{N}(C)-1$.

Comment: Finally, since there is at least one circuit $C$ such that $(v_1,v_n)\in E(C)$, the total sum with respect to $N'$ is strictly less than the total sum with respect to $N$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, taking a better enumeration suffices. If $(v_n,v_1)\not\in E$ then consider the enumeration $N'=(v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_{n-1},v_1,v_n)$. It is easy to see that for any circuit $C$ such that $(v_1,v_n)\not\in E(C)$ we have $i_N(C)=i_{N'}(C)$. For any circuit $C$ such that $(v_1,v_n)\in E(C)$ (and there is one since $T$ is strong) we get $i_{N'}(C)=i_N(C)-1$, contradicting our assumption on $N$.

Comment: Why there is only 1? Is the only circuit you're talking about the one passing through all the vertices? How can we prove that?

Comment: There can be more than 1. What I meant to say was there is **at least** one.

Comment: How about if $v_1$ was connected to all the other vertices by a forward edge? I mean $(v_1,v_2), (v_1,v_3), (v_1,v_4) ... \in E(C)$ ? Then they will all be back edges in your enumeration

Comment: Note that any circuit $C$ that contains $v_1$ but not $(v_1,v_n)$ will contain the edges $(v_i,v_1), (v_1,v_j)$ for some $i,j>1$.

Comment: You mean I was wrong by saying "...all..."? Or is it something else that you mean it? But even if they weren't all forward, how can we know that the number of forward edges was more than the number of backward edges in the first enumeration?(Because if this is right then it is done by the enumeration you've given) Maybe I didn't get your point exactly, please explain it more to me.

Comment: Are you Erlang of the Bronze medalist IMO?

Comment: @FareedAF What I was saying is that for every forward edge incident to $v_1$ in any circuit $C$ you will get one backward edge right next to it in the same circuit $C$, so intuitively they will cancel out. Can you see now why the third sentence in my answer is true?

Comment: Not quite well actually, because for example $2$ circuits might have the same forward edge to $v_1$ but 2 different backward edges from $v_1$ (considering your enumeration). Isn't this case possible? If it is, then the number of backward edges in your enumeration is more than that in the original enumeration, right?

Comment: Yes that case is possible but it doesn't change my argument. My answer asses 1 circuit at a time.